# Can you use Facebook messenger if you're not friends?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

Why do I have names in my Facebook messenger that I am not friends with on Facebook?

Comment: Well you can have those names in your chatlist if someone has initiated group chat. And it can be customized in privacy settings!

Answer (score 1):

Facebook messenger app requires your mobile/contact number while setting up at initial stage when you download the app. This happens to all those who use the Facebook messenger app on their mobile phones. This feature helps the messenger to sync your phone contact with the Facebook contact/friends despite of the fact that your phone contacts are not your friends on Facebook.